# Extract Number from Text

Tags: javascript, json, zapier

Trying to grab a number from this JSON:

```
{
   "event":"shipment.status_update",
   "status":"in_transit",
   "updated_at":"2017-12-08T03:29:24.591+00:00",
   "shipment_id":2023431,
   "shid":2023431,
   "shipment_public_id":"shp_tnwr4GjD",
   "order_number":"MF17966",
   "source_system_id":null
}
```

Need to extract the number after **shid**. In this case, **2023431**.

**Edit:**

What I'm trying to do is build a Zapier workflow that:

1. Catches a raw hook
2. Runs a Javascript that outputs the **shid** value from above
3. Then I'm going to use that value to call a webservice
4. And finally send an email to an individual

I'm able to catch the hook and don't anticipate any trouble with the 3rd and 4th part of the workflow. But capturing that **shid** is proving troublesome.

So far I've tried using the following in the Code element:

```
shid = (inputData["shid"]);
output = shid;
```

Comment: Why not decode that (it looks like JSON) and address the element instead of brute-forcing a pattern match (which is a very brittle strategy for the type of data you're presenting)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is just asking for a solution, sans personal research/effort.

Comment: Didn't get anywhere with RegEx. Trying to extract for a Zapier workflow.

Comment: This can be closed. Should have spent more time with it before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `json.loads()`

```
import json
output = json.loads(text)
print (output["shid"])
```

the number will be printed out.